# UItableView with static cells contains 2 UItableviews each with custom cell with dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with static cells it holds multiple items:

1. `UILabel` with dynamic height
2. Two `UITableView`s with dynamic content and custom cells

I want to expand the content of those 2 `UITableView`s on top of the parent `UITableView`. The problem is that I can't configure the cells content inside the 2 nested `UITableView`s.

Here is a screenshot of my main.storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! to be able to better answer your question, it is recommended to share your code and describe in detail what part is not working. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not recommend using nested table views. Alternative of this is UICollectionView, which is highly customisable.

If you still want to use nested table views. Subclass UITableViewCell and add table view whatever custom view you want to add.

Comment: Please consider adding references for the statements, or the alternative, and make sure to explain in a little more detail what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this line in your view controller to automatically adjust height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.commentsTableView.estimatedRowHeight 
}
```